# hook_form_alter to create table field

Tags: forms

I created a form which takes user input for fields: title, link, date and description, however I have another field which is guid and it cannot be user created. This field needs to be created with hook_form_alter() which takes the user inputted link and concatenates a string to the front and then return it to the submit handler for db_insert. How can I go onto doing this? here is my submit handler

```
function rss_list_creator_form_submit($form, &$form_alter) {
//$GUID = returns GUID from hook_form_alter()
$query = db_merge('rss_table')
->key( array('GUID' => $GUID))
->fields( array(
'title' => $form_state['values']['title'],
'link' => $form_state['values']['url'],
//'GUID' => $GUID,
'date' => $form_state['values']['date'],
'description' => $form_state['values']['description'],
))
->execute();
}
```

**I solved my problem, since I have two forms available I needed to enclose the code in a switch statement. Here is the code block:

```
function rss_list_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 switch ($form_id) {
  case 'rss_list_creator_form':
  if(isset($form_state['values']['url'])){
    $guid = 'tag:news.google.com,2005:cluster=' . $form_state['values']['url'];
  }
  $form['guid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => !empty($guid) ? $guid : '',
  );
  break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with hidden field. You can make #guid field a [hidden](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#hidden) field. in your hook_form_alter() #guid initially will hold the default value to empty on submission, you can make #guid fields value to whatever you want to make.

```
funciton mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if(isset($form_state['values']['url']){
    $guid = 'extra string' . $form_state['values']['url'];
  }
  $form['#guid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => !empty($guid) ? $guid : '';
    );
}
```

Comment: I have another issue, since guid is a primary key, it is giving me this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: guid in rss_list_creator_form_submit() (line 252 of C:\wamp\www\internarias\sites\default\modules\rss_list\rss_list.module).
Notice: Undefined index: guid in rss_list_creator_form_submit() (line 256 of C:\wamp\www\internarias\sites\default\modules\rss_list\rss_list.module).
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'GUID' cannot be null:

Comment: Are you calling hook_form_alter manually as displayed in your submit handler? you should not call that manually. this hook will be called automatically. simple get the guid value as `$guid = $form_state['values']['guid']`. From your error _error: Notice: Undefined variable: guid in rss_list_creator_form_submit() (line 252 of_ it looks like there is no value in $guid variable. make sure that it have some value before you do db_insert. As $guid is primary key and it doesn't have any value that's why its throwing _PDOException._

Comment: cool. I forget to mention the condition which check `$form_id` because `hook_form_alter` will be called for each form on the page.